Kibana Visualization Table from array
I have been searching around and I couldn't find an answer for this issue and it's most likely not supported by Kibana unless I break down my array into a new index, which is something I wanted to avoid.
Regarding my question, assuming we have a few documents within a time range and each document has an array with a date and an event type, would I be able to extract the date and event type into a table?
here is an example of the array:
"chargeCycleEvents": [
      {
        "eventType": "PLUGGED_IN",
        "dateOfEvent": "2024-06-18T19:45:36.364+01:00",
        "additionalData": null
      },
      {
        "eventType": "CHARGE_STARTS",
        "dateOfEvent": "2024-06-18T19:45:36.364+01:00",
        "additionalData": null
      },
      {
        "eventType": "CHARGE_UPDATE_EVENT",
        "dateOfEvent": "2024-06-18T20:03:59.971+01:00",
        "additionalData": "SoC: 30"
      },
      {
        "eventType": "CHARGE_UPDATE_EVENT",
        "dateOfEvent": "2024-06-18T20:18:43.498+01:00",
        "additionalData": "SoC: 32"
      },
      {
        "eventType": "CHARGE_UPDATE_EVENT",
        "dateOfEvent": "2024-06-18T20:33:26.094+01:00",
        "additionalData": "SoC: 34"
      }]


The end result I'm after is to have a table sorting out the values of dateOfEvent and having the correspondent eventType as the value.
I also tried the vega-lite to do it as a custom chart but I didn't had that much luck.
